# github contributions graph doesn't show my contributions

Tags: spring, github

I'm using github associated with spring tool suite. My commit & push activity is recorded on the 'Public Activity' page but not shown on contributions graph and I don't know why.

Check these out

## Public Activity page - check the latest push record please

https://github.com/yaboong?tab=activity

## Overview page - check out the contribution graph please

https://github.com/yaboong

Comment: Check out [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/).  Are you missing any of the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked out your commits. The ones that are showing up use email `dan*********oo@gmail.com` whereas the ones that do not use email `yab*********ub@gmail.com`.

You should add the missing email to your Github account. Use [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-email-address-to-your-github-account/).

If you want to use a specific email for local commits, use:

```
$ git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
$ git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Git for desktop I'm using was set to the second e-mail address without recognition. Thanks for letting me know :)